# Windows Phone 8.1 WebView ignores hashfragments when calling GoBack()

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

The title describes the question.

Context: You have a single page app which relies on hash fragments for routing inside the WebView.
Problem: if you call webViewControll.GoBack() the WebView ignores all the hash fragments and return back to the plain URL (without the hash fragment).

Example:

Hompage: www.example.com

Navigation1:  www.example.com -> www.example.com/#!/about

Navigation2: www.example.com/#!/about -> www.example.com/#!/contact

if i call GoBack() the WebView loads: www.example.com instead of: www.example.com/#!/about
Any thoughts? Workaround? Comments? Will be greatly appreciated.